# How to use swf vpaid?

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject, vast

VPAID may be js or swf.

If I have js then everything is simple, I just do:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = onLoad;
script.src = "https://somedomain.net/vpaid.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

And when JS file is loaded onLoad is called.

```
function onLoad() {
    var adUnit = getVPAIDAd();
}
```

And now I have an adUnit that have some API:

```
adUnit.initAd
adUnit.handshakeVersion
...
```

And another methods to controll ad.

But if I have swf then I do not know what to do.

I have URL:

```
https://somedomain.net/vpaid.swf
```

I can use swfobject to create object:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
    "https://somedomain.net/vpaid.swf",
    "myContent", "640", "480", "9.0.0"
);
```

But I do not know how can I get AdUnit. I want to get AdUnit from this swf and I want this AdUnit to have the same API:

```
adUnit.initAd
adUnit.handshakeVersion
...
```

but I don't how to do that :(.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement you own AS3/Flash player to do so.

The player will receive the VPAID resource url via `flash.external.ExternalInterface` or you hand over the entire parsed VAST to the flash player (which I would prefer).

AS3 sample:

```
/**
 * Setup listeners
 */
private function setup():void {
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("player_load", load);
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("player_exec", execute);
}

/**
 * Hand over VAST
 */       
private function load(data:*):void {
    try {
        var result:* = _internalPlayer.load(new VAST(data.vast));
        callExternal(data.callback, result);
    } catch(e.*) {
        callExternal(data.callback, e);
    }
}

/**
 * Implement something to control the player from JS via ExternalInterface
 */
private function execute(data:*):* {
    try {
        var result:* = new Command(data.command).execute();
        callExternal(data.callback, result);
    } catch(e.*) {
        callExternal(data.callback, e);
    }
}

private function callExternal(target:String, args:*):void {
    if(ExternalInterface.available)
        ExternalInterface.call(target, args);
    else
        trace('ExternalInterface unavailable');
}
```

JS sample:

```
embedded_swf['player_load']({
    'vast': vast, // parsed VAST
    'callback': 'window.player.events.backchannel' // some available method to send success/error messages to
});
[...]
embedded_swf['player_exec']({
    'command': {
        'command': 'play',
        'target': 'ad.id.1' // some identifier flash-player can work with
    },
    'callback': 'window.player.events.backchannel'
});
```

Of course this is just an example of how you could do it and just fraction of what to do at all. But I hope it helps somehow.

Have a nice day.